# Failover for AppFabric Cache session state provider

Tags: asp.net, session, appfabric, failover, appfabric-cache

Hey stackoverflow fans,

I have a question about AppFabric cache. We have 3 AppFabric cache nodes configured as one cache cluster to achieve High Availability. We use it for sessions in Asp.Net applications.

Builtin AppFabric cache session state provider has such configuration

```
  <dataCacheClient>    
    <hosts>
      <host name="CacheServer1" cachePort="22233"/>
      <host name="CacheServer2" cachePort="22233"/>
      <host name="CacheServer3" cachePort="22233"/>
    </hosts>
  </dataCacheClient>
```

When I try to simulate fail, and stoping one node in that cache cluster, then session state provider begin to throw an errors that it can't connect to that node. It happens not for each request, but for some of them. I thought that session state provider will understand that node is failed, and won't use it for some time, but it still tries to use it. and application users affected by these errors.

Is there a way to force session state provider to not use this cache node for some time? Or maybe some automatic algorithm that will check node availability and use it again, when node is restored?

Comment: Did you find the cause and/Or solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately no, we are still don't decide about AppFabric usage. This behavior isn't good for us.

Comment: The problem is that AppFabric replicates data between other nodes some time, from our tests between 20 seconds up to 4 minutes. And during that time data from that node won't be available. Even if we enabled Secondaries parameter for cache....

Comment: What was the session provider did you try? AppFabricCacheSessionStoreProvider or DistributedSessionProvider?

Comment: We used DistributedSessionProvider as it was in SDK.